# iOS not able to upload images on Mobile Data/4G network where in Wifi it is working fine

Tags: ios, swift, server, image-uploading, nsurlsession

I am using NSURLSesssion upload task to upload images to server,sending in Bytes.It is working fine in wifi.But when i upload using MobileData/4G LTE network it shows -1001 error code.
1.Increased server side timeout to 4 minutes.
2.Tried with small kb size image
Still issue exists only on 4GLTE networks.

Note:Same service API works in Andriod.

Please let me know what will be the issue.?

```
    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    [request setCachePolicy:cachePolicy];
    [self prepareMethod:methodURL methodType:methodType dataInBody:dataInBody contentType:contentType withRequest:request];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [NSURLRequest allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:@“yyyy.abc.com"];



    NSMutableData * bodyData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    params = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"userparams"]mutableCopy];

        for (NSString *param in params)
        {
            if (![param isEqualToString:@"file"]) {
                [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            }
        }

        // add image data
        [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpeg\"\r\n", @"file"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [bodyData appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [bodyData appendData:[params objectForKey:@"file"]];
        [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



    //NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    // sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 120.0;
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    NSURLSessionUploadTask* uploadtask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:bodyData completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){

              if (!error)
              {
                  NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
                  HttpResponse * response = [[HttpResponse alloc] initWithHttpURLResponse:httpResponse withData:data];



                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                      if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(connectionFinishedLoading:)]) {
                          [delegate connectionFinishedLoading:response];
                      }
                  });

              }
              else
              {
                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                      if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(connectionFailedWithError:)])
                      {
                          [delegate connectionFailedWithError:error];
                      }
                  });
              }


          }];
    [uploadtask resume];

}
```

Comment: How about showing some code used so that it's possible to see how you have set everything up.

Comment: I can't imagine why you're sticking the parameter data into NSUserDefaults; that is almost certainly a mistake.  And allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost is also invariably a bad idea.  Neither of these is your problem, though.  A 1001 error is a timeout.  This usually indicates that the server is not reachable over the cellular network.